# How do I get my compiler to locate the X11 header files?

Tags: 13.04, xorg, c++, opengl, makefile

I'm trying to use GLEW and XServer / X11 in a C++ app as instructed in Chapter 15 of the OpenGL Superbible, 5th ed.

I'm using this Makefile:

```
LIBDIRS = -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib
INCDIRS = -I/usr/include -L/usr/include 

CC = g++
CFLAGS = $(COMPILERFLAGS) -g $(INCDIRS)
LIBS = -lX11 -lXi -lXmu -lm -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL

GLXBasics: GLXBasics.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o GLXBasics $(LIBDIRS) GLXBasics.cpp $(LIBS)

clean:
        rm -f *.o
```

and getting this result:

```
GLXBasics.cpp:4:18: fatal error: glew.h: No such file or directory
```

[EDIT:]
After fixing a silly coding error, I now have trouble with X11, and my GLEW issues are history.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXmu
```

[/EDIT]

If I comment out the inclusion of `glew.h`, it fails on the inclusion of `glxew.h`.

I have sudo-copied and pasted `glew.h` and `glxew.h` to `/usr/include/GL`. (Which is where I believe they're supposed to be?)

Forgive me in case I forgot to include something in my question - anything you'd like to know or see from my terminal just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `GLXBasics.cpp:4:18: fatal error: glew.h: No such file or directory`

I guess you have a line there with something like the line below?

```
#include <glew.h>
```

Change that to

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
```

This is required, as you've copied it into the `GL/` subdirectory of the search paths specified in your `INCDIRS`.

---

> I have sudo-copied and pasted `glew.h` and `glxew.h` to `/usr/include/GL`

I would recommend using `/usr/local/include/GL` as that will avoid conflicts with Ubuntu packages.

> I now have trouble with X11, and my GLEW issues are history.
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXi
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXmu
> ```
>
> because they are in `/usr/local/include`?

This error is is about the libraries (binaries), not about the headers. In case you install them manually, you should place them in `/usr/local/lib` instead of `include/` (that's for header files). Or perhaps you're just missing the X development packages here? Please ask this in a new question if this has nothing to do with your header files.

Don't forget to update your `INCDIR` and `LIBDIR` to include the new `/usr/local/include` directories, e.g.:

```
INCDIRS = -I/usr/include -L/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/include
```

Comment: @mynameisnafe Please **edit** your question to provide more details. That is how this site works - comments aren't fit for that.

Comment: Ackowlnedged.. this is literally my first question!